# Insert text element after text element with link in google doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

i have a text with link which is inserted through user action from google add-on, user can insert more texts as well simultaneously with add-on so how can i insert space between consecutive text insertions.

Current scenario:

```
 [Text1][Text2][Text3]
```

What I want is:

```
 [Text1] [Text2] [Text3]
```

current insertion code:

```
cursor = doc.getCursor();    
    if (cursor) {
        var text = cursor.insertText(textStr);
        if (text) {
            text.setLinkUrl(url);
            text.setUnderline(false);
            text.setForegroundColor('#000000');
            var len = text.getText().length - 1;
            try {
                var pos = doc.newPosition(text, cursor.getOffset() + Number(len));
                doc.setCursor(pos);
            }
            catch (ex) {
                var pos = doc.newPosition(text, cursor.getOffset() + Number(len) - 1);
                doc.setCursor(pos);
            }
        }
        else {
            DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text here.');
        }
    }
    else {
        DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find cursor.');
    }
```

Comment: What is the current issue of your script?

Comment: don't insert space between text insertions

Answer (score 1):

### You insert `textStr` twice

because using `var text = cursor.insertText(textStr);` and `text.setLinkUrl(url);` is equal to calling the method `insertText(textStr)` twice.

To insert a space between two sections

you can insert after `textStr` a string containing just a space with `cursor.insertText(" ");`

Here an idea how you can modify your code in a simple way to incorporate a space after `textStr`:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var textStr='I am a text';
  var url='https://stackoverflow.com';
  cursor = doc.getCursor();    
    if (cursor) {
            var text=cursor.insertText(textStr).setLinkUrl(url);
            if (text) {
             text.setUnderline(false);
             text.setForegroundColor('#000000'); 
             var len = text.getText().length;
             var pos = doc.newPosition(text, Number(len));
             doc.setCursor(pos);
             var space=cursor.insertText(" ");
             pos = doc.newPosition(space, 1);
             doc.setCursor(pos);
            }
           else {
            DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text here.');
           }
    }
    else {
        DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find cursor.');
    }
}
```